# Group a Datatable and copy to another table C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

There is already a question here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121248/report-generation-in-asp-net". I have same scenario where i have stocked on a specific point.

Please Help.

My DataTable has three columns

```
Name  Plot   Area
a     12     .90
a     13     .30
b     12     .45
b     13     .46
c     13     .98
```

I want my result to be

```
Name  Plot  Area
a     12    .90
      13    .30
b     12    .45
      13    .46
c     13    .98
```

And this is what i have tried . I have grouped this to linq and need to copy to another table. How can i achieve this :

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            DataTable dtMain = new DataTable();
            dtMain.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dtMain.Columns.Add("Plot", typeof(int));
            dtMain.Columns.Add("Area", typeof(decimal));

            DataRow dr1 = dtMain.NewRow();
            dr1["Name"] = "a";
            dr1["Plot"] = 12;
            dr1["Area"] = .90;
            dtMain.Rows.Add(dr1);

            DataRow dr2 = dtMain.NewRow();
            dr2["Name"] = "a";
            dr2["Plot"] = 13;
            dr2["Area"] = .30;
            dtMain.Rows.Add(dr2);

            DataRow dr3 = dtMain.NewRow();
            dr3["Name"] = "b";
            dr3["Plot"] = 12;
            dr3["Area"] = .45;
            dtMain.Rows.Add(dr3);
            DataRow dr4 = dtMain.NewRow();
            dr4["Name"] = "b";
            dr4["Plot"] = 13;
            dr4["Area"] = .46;
            dtMain.Rows.Add(dr4);
            DataRow dr5 = dtMain.NewRow();
            dr5["Name"] = "c";
            dr5["Plot"] = 13;
            dr5["Area"] = .98;
            dtMain.Rows.Add(dr5);

            DataTable dtFinal = dtMain.Clone();

            var groupedData = (from b in dtMain.AsEnumerable()
                               group b by b.Field<string>("Name") into g
                               select new
                              {
                                  Name = g.Key,
                                  Plot = g.Select(x => x.Field<int>("Plot")),
                                  Area = g.Select(x => x.Field<Decimal>("Area")),
                              }).ToList();

      //Next what should i do here.CopyToDataTable() no longer getting the correct data.
       dtFinal = groupedData.ToList().CopyToDataTable();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception objEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(objEx);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't be afraid to use loops ;)

```
var nameGroups = dtMain.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Name"));

foreach (var nameGroup in nameGroups)
{
    bool isFirstRow = true;
    foreach (DataRow row in nameGroup)
    {
        DataRow newRow = dtFinal.Rows.Add();
        newRow.SetField("Name", isFirstRow ? nameGroup.Key : "");
        newRow.SetField("Plot", row.Field<int>("Plot"));
        newRow.SetField("Area", row.Field<decimal>("Area"));
        isFirstRow = false;
    }              
}
```

LINQ   is not supposed to cause side-effects. So use it to select what you need to create the table.

Result:

```
a      12     0.9
       13     0.3
b      12     0.45
       13     0.46
c      13     0.98
```

If you insist on avoiding loops, here is the reason why you should use them. Look at this ugly, inefficient and strange query:

```
DataTable dtFinal = dtMain.Clone();
dtFinal = dtMain.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Name"))
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.Select((row, index)=> index == 0
        ? dtFinal.LoadDataRow(new object[]{ grp.Key, row.Field<int>("Plot"), row.Field<decimal>("Area")}, true)
        : dtFinal.LoadDataRow(new object[]{ "", row.Field<int>("Plot"), row.Field<decimal>("Area")}, true)))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: This is the correct Answer. Mr. Downvoter , can you please explain why this answer cannot be accepted ? @Tim Schmelter - Can this solution achived without Loop ?

Comment: @kumarch1: no, because LINQ also uses loops. This is the most effcient and most readable way to achieve what you want. But if you insist on a LINQ query you can use `LoadDataRow` i have edited my answer to provid  you a "nice" query.

Comment: Thank you. and you had mentioned " ugly, inefficient and strange query" but I loved it

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to make `Name` appear only once, you need to change your query:

```
dtMain.AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(b => b.Field<string>("Name"))
  .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x,idx) => new
                            {
                                Name = idx == 0 ? g.Key : "",
                                Plot = x.Field<int>("Plot"),
                                Area = x.Field<Decimal>("Area"),
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Your result is a list, OP wants to create a `DataTable`.

Comment: Yes. I need it as a DataTable - Means my left hand side should be a DataTable .

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 0;
bool saveIndex = false;

DataTable table = sourceTable.Copy();

for(int i=0; i< table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if(i==0)
      continue;

    if(!saveIndex)
       index = i-1;

   if(table.Rows[i]["Name"] == table.Rows[index]["Name"])
   {
        table.Rows[i]["Name"] = "";

        saveIndex = true;
   }
   else
   {
       saveIndex = false;
   }

}
```

I don't know the constrains of your fields, but this probably will help.

I wrote you this in your previous answer, hope it helps !

Answer (score -2):

```
var query = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<string>("RoomName") into grp
            select new
            {
                RoomName = grp.Key,
                WeekDuty = grp.First().Field<string>("WeekDuty")
            };
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Also, post answers based on the code in the question. The fields in your data table don't exist in the question making the answer not applicable. But the greatest bummer is that this doesn't do what's asked. They don't want a first of each group. The accepted answer is all this question needs.